# EntityFramework error when trigger SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Got an error stated

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

when I trigger `SaveChangesAsync()` function.  See my code below:

```
using (var context = new CommonDBContext()) {
    var bbrs = await context.Table1
        .ToListAsync();

    var lastIndexToRemove = pimc.Result.IndexOf("UIX/");
    if (lastIndexToRemove > -1)
    {
        bbrPimcStr = pimc.Result.Remove(0, lastIndexToRemove);
    }

    foreach (var bbr in bbrs) {
        bbr.XBBR = xbbrStr;
        bbr.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        bbr.LastUpdatedBy = userId;

        if (!pimc.HasError)
        {
            var graveDKI = context.graveDKIStore
                .Where(x => x.RefId == bbr.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (graveDKI != null)
                graveDKI.GraveDKI = bbrPimcStr ;
            else
                context.graveDKIStore.Add(new graveDKIStore
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    GraveDKI = bbrPimcStr ,
                    RefId = bbr.Id,
                    MsgType = "PPIXFFT"
                });
        }
    }
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Got issue here
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code? thanks.

**Update:** Added exception stack.
[image: Error Stack]

Comment: And what is in `EntityValidationErrors`?

Comment: hi @RomanDoskoch, added a exception stack. please check updated questions. thanks

Comment: you have `EntityValidationErrors` with `Count = 1` - just open it and see what error do you have

Comment: Hi @RomanDoskoch, yes thanks for that! got the idea and got the issue fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: If you've fixed your issue, post an answer here so anyone having similar problem can benefit from it or, if this is your case specific issue just delete it as it won't make any use.

Comment: will do, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by checking the length of the character, it might be different errors base on what data annotation or validator annotation that you placed on your object.  To double check if your validations are correct, you can check through exception stack under `EntityValidationErrors` to get more in-depth information about it, see image below.

```
public class GraveDKIStore {
...
[MaxLength(5)] // The issue is here so I changed it to 10.
public string MsgType { get; set; }
...
}
```

[image]

P.S. thanks to Roman Doskoch for a very helpful advice.